# BeautifulSoup returning None during site scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Origin site to check if given game title is available for MacOS. For example The Sims 4 (https://www.origin.com/pol/pl-pl/store/the-sims/the-sims-4). There's Apple logo icon, which I believe would be great indicator to check for. So I've looked into code and found it:

```
<i ng-repeat="platform in platforms track by $index" class="otkicon otkicon-apple"></i>
```

Now into Python code:

```
page = requests.get(origin_site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
result = soup.find("i", class_="otkicon otkicon-apple")
if result:
    origin_answer = "YES"
```

Aaaaand it returns None.
For other websites (Steam, Gog, Epic) it works. I've been googling it for past 2h and tried every solution I could find. None (nomen omen) of them worked. I've also tried with headers, also nothing. I seriously got no idea what to do next.

Comment: This looks like an Angular site, the content you see in the browser is dynamically generated by the browser. BS can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website needs JS to work, and requests does not supports it.
But you can:

- If any, use an API.
- Use [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) which fully supports Javascript.
- Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) Python binding, which will allow you to automates your browser.